# Are two installations of WordPress on the same domain (no subdomains) ok?

Tags: installation

Can I install one WordPress at http://example.com and another WordPress at http://example.com/demo with no problems?

I've already done this using Softaculous, and it seems to be working, but will I run into obscure issues down the road?

Comment: Why would you do that instead of utilizing a sub-domain?

Comment: @Darth_Vader, some times you want the site to look as if it is one site, for example when there are localizations that you do not want them to feel like they are on separate site. It is really more of an esthetics thing that probably should be avoided when possible but from time to time there is a use for such configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but the "gotcha" to look for are the default htaccess rewrite rules that wordpress uses. With them the "front" wordpress is going to try to parse all url which are not mapped to actual files and therefor will mask the urls of the second site. You will have to manually edit the "front" htaccess to explicitly exclude the directory in which the other wordpress reside.

Other things to look for are robots.txt and sitemaps, especially if the front install is at the root of the domain.

Answer (score -2):

Yes - no problem. You can also install multi-site and set up two different sites with one WP multisite.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your first 3 words are correct while the rest is irrelevant :(